# How to add confirm password section in the code below?

Tags: php, passwords, forgot-password

This php code is my password rest form. I want to add confirm password section in this code. The enter new password section is already here. Anybody help please.

```
   <?php do_action('noo_reset_password_form_before'); 
        $rp_key = isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? $_GET['key'] : '';
        $rp_login = isset( $_GET['login'] ) ? $_GET['login'] : '';
    ?>
    <div class="account-form">
        <div class="account-reset-password-form">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="noo-reset-password-form" method="post">
                <div style="display: none">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset_password"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="rp_key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rp_key ); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="rp_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rp_login ); ?>" />
                    <?php wp_nonce_field('reset-password')?>
                </div>
                <div class="noo-messages noo-message-notice">
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php _e('Enter your new password below.', 'noo'); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row required-field">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="password"><?php _e('New password','noo')?></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" required autofocus name="password" id="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions form-group text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><?php esc_html_e('Reset Password','noo')?></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php do_action('noo_reset_password_form_after'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group row required-field">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="password"><?php _e('New password','noo')?></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" required autofocus name="password" id="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

you add confirm_password

```
<div class="form-group row required-field">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="confirm_password"><?php _e('New password','noo')?></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" required autofocus name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the you check it :3

```
if ($_POST["password"] === $_POST["confirm_password"]) {
   // success!
}
else {
   // failed :(
}
```

you can add realtime check with jquery

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#confirm_password").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
       // fail!
    else
        // success!
}
```

and finally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#password, #confirm_password").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

Comment: under html or create a js file and include it.. 
[Using Javascript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)